# Cisco Aironet 1200 Series AP Configuration

Tags: cisco, configuration, access-point

I am attempting to configure a new CISCO Aironet 1200 Series Access Point to have a fixed IP. I have been searching online and I have come to the conclusion that the default IP address of this device is 10.0.0.1.

These are the steps I have taken:

- My machine is plugged directly into the Ethernet port (not the Console port) of the AP.
- My Ethernet adapter is set to 10.0.0.2.
- I have reset the AP by holding the Mode button while powering up the device.

The issue remains that I can not access 10.0.0.1 through the web, nor can I ping that address.

Comment: So, use the console cable.

Comment: Are you sure that this is an autonomous AP and not a lightweight AP? Can you copy and paste the console output when you connect to the console cable and start a console session and then reboot the AP?

Comment: [There's a section here titled "How do I distinguish between a regular (autonomous) AP and an LAP?"](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/wireless/ps430/products_qanda_item09186a00806a4da3.shtml)  Might be worth a read.

Comment: The 1200-series access points use DHCP. The 1100-series have the default IP address you're talking about. Do you not have DHCP on your network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you use the console cable to connect to the device.  This way you know you've got a connection that works and isn't dependent on network configurations on both sides.

Once you boot it up with the console cable connected, you can configure it to whatever IP address you want it to have, as well as whatever else, without having to rely on "the internet" being right about the default settings either.

Answer (score 1):

These devices grab a DHCP address by default. There is no default IP. As mentioned before, this only applies if it is a full AP and not a lightweight model. Posting the Cisco part number of your unit will help.

This gives some options. If you don't have dhcp, you can move the device to a DHCP network just for initial config... Or even share an IP from your laptop or PC.

Another option is to arp an address to the device. [See the Cisco link detailing the process](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/wireless/ps430/products_qanda_item09186a008009483e.shtml).

Initial access will be via http to the device IP. Username:Pass is Cisco:Cisco

Otherwise, your console cable is your friend...

Edit:

[From Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/wireless/ps430/products_qanda_item09186a008009483e.shtml): 

A. By default, the AP requests an IP address through DHCP.

*Cisco IOS Releases 12.3(2)JA and later change the default behavior of APs requesting an IP address from a DHCP server:*

*When you connect a 1200 or 1230 series AP with a default configuration to your LAN, the AP requests an IP address from your DHCP server. If it does not receive an address, it continues to send requests indefinitely.*

*When you connect an 1100 series AP with a default configuration to your LAN, the 1100 series AP makes several attempts to get an IP address from the DHCP server. If it does not receive an address, it assigns itself the IP address 10.0.0.1 for five minutes. During this five minute window, you can browse to the default IP address and configure a static address. If after five minutes the AP is not reconfigured, it discards the 10.0.0.1 address and reverts to requesting an address from the DHCP server. If it does not receive an address, it sends requests indefinitely. If you miss the five minute window for browsing to the AP at 10.0.0.1, you can power-cycle the AP to repeat the process.*

Answer (score 1):

You are confused most likely because it sounds like you have only ever dealt with home based WAP units. Such as Linksys, Netgear, etc.

Generally speaking, Cisco WAP's are setup and configured in much of the same way all enterprise Cisco equipment is programmed, though console cable, telnet, ssh.

I find many of the younger administrators that have no network configuration experience to expect that any kind of real configuration occurs in a GUI interface (cisco cna no where near useful as console).

If you have never configured a Cisco WAP though console before you will most likely finding it very confusing.

Lets start by getting you into the GUI by manually configuring the ip address (assuming you dont have dhcp)

Connect a Cisco Console cable (if your not sure what it looks like google it).

Once connected, depending on the default config it might ask for a username and password. If it does it will be either "cisco" or "Cisco" for both username and password.

Once logged in type "en" It might ask for a password again, If it does its again either "cisco" or "Cisco" don't use quotation marks.

Now type in console

```
    conf t 
    interface BVI1 
    ip address <ip address you want to use> <net mask>   
    (ctrl+z on keyboard)
    conf t
    ip default-gateway <yourgateway>
   (ctrl+z on keyboard)
    wr mem
```

hope this helps, should now have the ip address you set. LEARN CONSOLE!

Answer (score 0):

I usually hook an Ethernet cable directly from my laptop to the device. Then i can statically configure my laptop, then make an ARP table entry for the device.

Comment: This might be more useful if you went a little into what that entails.  (IMO)